# Multiple In-Reply-To

Tags: email, email-headers

Mail user agents usually display threads of Emails by chaining messages together according to the *In-Reply-To* and *References* header fields that contain the *Message-ID*s of other messages. Although a mail usually only replies to one other message, it may be the case that one message answers multiple others. [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) allows multiple entries in both fields. What can I expect when I send an email that *References* or is *In-Reply-To* multiple IDs this way?

- Is it good practice to do so?
- Does it confuse widespread MUAs?
- Is there any common ground on how to display such a message in a
  threaded view?

Answer (score 3):

> The "In-Reply-To:" field will contain the contents of the
>      "Message-ID:" field of the message to which this one is a reply (the
>      "parent message").  If there is more than one parent message, then
>      the "In-Reply-To:" field will contain the contents of all of the
>      parents' "Message-ID:" fields.  If there is no "Message-ID:" field in
>      any of the parent messages, then the new message will have no "In-
>      Reply-To:" field.

Technically there COULD be a reason where you would reply to multiple emails and it would be valid to place multiple message ids in the In-Reply-To header. I can’t think of any program that actually supports this. As to MUAs they won’t care the delivery that the MUA cares about is the To, Cc, Bcc headers.

The In-Reply-To header and References header would control how threads are displayed. Not sure if any mail clients would have an issue handling the multiple In-Reply-To headers. 99% of the time there would only be a single message ID in the In-Reply-To header. So it’s feasible mail applications won’t support it. However they would support the additional reference entries. And this shouldn’t pose an issue.

Answer (score 0):

> What can I expect when I send an email that `References` or is `In-Reply-To` multiple IDs this way?

> Is it good practice to do so?

As you said the current standard (RFC 5322) defines that, so why should it be a problem to adhere to that standard?
Also note that multiple IDs in `References` is typical, while it's not very common for `In-Reply-To` (see section "3.6.4. Identification Fields" of RFC 5322).

> Does it confuse widespread MUAs?

Like above: A MUA that does not support the standard is not worth using it IMHO.
However most MUAs make it very hard to impossible to reply to multiple messages at once; one exception I know is using Emacs' [Supercite](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/sc.html).

Also make sure you don't mix things:
The `In-reply-to` header field does *not* specify to which senders the message is being sent; instead it merely adds a reference.
Details can be found in section "3.6.4. Identification Fields" of RFC 5322.

In addition I think one can confuse *users* much more than MUAs when *not* using the MUA's "reply" function when replying to a message (and using "compose" instead.

> Is there any common ground on how to display such a message in a threaded view?

Obviously the graph of messages is a DAG (*Directed A-cyclic Graph*), with the special case of *tree* in most cases.
So the question is mostly equivalent to "*How to display a DAG or tree?*"
In text-based interfaces you could do it by indenting the child messages relative to their parent messages, possibly allowing to collapse and/or expand child nodes.
The latter is probably much more comfortable and easier to grasp in graphical user interfaces.